# Windows 7 Cannot Join Domain

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-7, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm having trouble connecting a Windows 7 computer to my Domain.  I'm running a private network inside VMWare Workstation and have successfully connected a WinXP and Win10 machine to the network without any issues. However, this Windows 7 machine is giving me grief,

I'm running a Windows 2012 R2 Server that's my AD, DNS, and DHCP server.  The Windows 7 machine is able to utilize the DHCP features and is autoassigned an IP address.

When trying to join the domain, I get the following Error:

```
An Attempt to Resolve the DNS name of a domain controller in the domain being joined has failed. Please verify this client is configured to reach a DNS server that can resolve DNS names in the target domain.
```

[Screenshot of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Eknc.png)

I've tried searching google for solutions with no luck. I've set up a Reverse Lookup on the DNS server, changed the Authorization settings, and a few other things without any luck.

Has anyone had this issue before? How can I get this computer to join the domain?

EDIT: Forgot to include that I'm able to ping the DC without any issues. I can also access the Windows Server from the Windows 7 machine via the `\\BNET-DC1` name. Network connectivity is fine, just unable to join the domain

EDIT 2: Trying to join with the DNS name rather than the NetBIOS name and I get this error:

```
Note: This information is intended for a network administrator.  If you are not your network's administrator, notify the administrator that you received this information, which has been recorded in the file C:\Windows\debug\dcdiag.txt.

The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for domain "BNET.domain":

The error was: "DNS name does not exist."
(error code 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR)

The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.BNET.domain

Common causes of this error include the following:

- The DNS SRV records required to locate a AD DC for the domain are not registered in DNS. These records are registered with a DNS server automatically when a AD DC is added to a domain. They are updated by the AD DC at set intervals. This computer is configured to use DNS servers with the following IP addresses:

1.1.1.1
192.168.8.10

- One or more of the following zones do not include delegation to its child zone:

BNET.domain
domain
. (the root zone)
```

EDIT 3: `ipconfig /all` results from Windows 7 Machine: [Screenshot of ipconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQEmE.png)

EDIT 4: ### SOLUTION ###

This is only a theory because all evidence has been removed.  I logged into the one of the other machines in the domain and tried doing and `nslookup bnet.domain` and it came back with an error. This meant that something in my DNS was corrupt.  I demoted my DC and removed the DNS role. Then re-installed DNS and re-promoted my DC. This set things back to default and I was able to connect to the domain on each of the computers in the network.

A few quick things to check for anyone else having this problem:

1. Make sure your client and server are on the same subnet. `ipconfig /all` is your friend. Use it.
2. Double check that the DNS Server address on the client is pointed towards your DC (if your DC is also pulling DNS-duty)
3. Use `nslookup [DOMAIN NAME]` to see if you have a valid DNS connection.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77907/discussion-on-question-by-andy-windows-7-cannot-join-domain).